# Will it be inappropriate to use "any shapes"

Tags: word-choice

From Google

> “Any” can be singular or plural when you use it as a pronoun,
> depending on whether it refers to a countable noun (like “book” or
> “books”) or an uncountable noun (like “water”). “Any” is singular when
> it modifies singular countable nouns, and it becomes plural when used
> with plural countable nouns.

The idiom

> "in any shape or form"

---

Will it be inappropriate to use *any shapes* like below? The context is for subject matter that is intangible, for e.g. cultural practices, dance, art, fashion ..etc

**Example 1**

1. Fashion is for ***any shape***
2. Fashion for ***any shapes***

**Example 2**

1. Dancing is for ***any shape***
2. Dancing is for ***any shapes***

Answer (score 1):

> Will it be inappropriate to use any shapes like below? The context is
> for subject matter that is intangible, for e.g. cultural practices,
> dance, art, fashion ..etc
>
> 1. This is for any shape
> 2. This is for any shapes

Without even more details or at least more complete sentences, it is difficult to judge which alternative is better; however, whether you use the singular or plural is usually guided by what you consider to be the default situation or the situation under discussion.

In addition, using the singular, even where the plural might be considered the default, is often used to stress that there are no exceptions.  In other words, when plural usage is an option, you have the choice of using the plural as a parallel construction to highlight that you are talking about the same situation or of using the singular to highlight that there are no exceptions.

Comment: Thanks! I've been pondering on this for some time. I've edited the example sentences, will both sentences in the two examples be acceptable and perceived as equivalent in their respective context?